# getting data from three different table and inserting it into new table

Tags: mysql

I have three tables with contents, now i want to get them and add it into new table but am having this sql error "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

here is the sql query.

```
insert into compare_year(yeara,yearb,yearc,data)
SELECT yeara
FROM table_1
UNION ALL
SELECT yearb, data
FROM table_2
UNION ALL
SELECT yearc
FROM table_3
```

below is how i created the tables

```
create table table_1(id int primary key auto_increment,yeara varchar(100));
create table table_2(id int primary key auto_increment,yearb varchar(100),data varchar(100));

create table table_3(id int primary key auto_increment,yearc varchar(100));
```

my new table is now

```
create table compare_year(id int primary key auto_increment,yeara varchar(100),yearb varchar(100),yearc varchar(100),data varchar(100))
```

please can someone help me. thanks

Comment: Do `year*` tables have exactly the same number of records?

Comment: What would be the relation between data that goes from three column of the three table into one row of compare_year table? what is the logic here?

Answer (score 0):

Note:when you union select queries,the number of columns should be equal.
and also you cannot insert mutiple select columns into a single row of another.

My solution will be like:

if three table contain same id,then you can do like this

insert into compare_year(yeara,yearb,yearc,data)
SELECT T1.yeara,T2.yearb,T3.yearc,T2.data
FROM table_1 T1
left Join table_2 T2 on T2.Id = T1.Id
left Join table_3 T3 on T3.Id = T2.Id

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want is a `JOIN` rather than a `UNION`. When you union two select statements, they must have the same number of fields in the `SELECT`. For example,

```
insert into compare_year(yeara)
SELECT yeara
FROM table_1
UNION ALL
SELECT yearb AS yeara
FROM table_2
UNION ALL
SELECT yearc AS yeara
FROM table_3
```

would be acceptable syntactically. If you want to join the tables,

```
INSERT INTO compare_year(yeara, yearb, yearc, data)
SELECT table_1.yeara, table_2.yearb, table_3.yearc, table_2.data
FROM table_1, table_2, table_3
```

but note that this is full cartesian product of the tables. It's likely you want some conditionals as well in a `WHERE` clause. It's also worth noting that the order of the select cause is what's important for the `INSERT`, not the field names.